# yum + what is the safety approach to remove all rpm's from i686 type from rhel 7.x version machines

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, x86

We want to remove the following rpm from all production machines servers , we have more the **152 servers** machines ( `rhel 7.6` ) , all Linux are `x86_64` architecture,

```
yum  remove *.i686  -y
```

this yum command will capture the rpm from `i686` type ( by use the "*" ) and remove them all

since we are using the “*” , I little worry if this approach is safety to remove the `i686` rpm's  ,

**my concern are**

1. dose yum command - `yum  remove *.i686`   removes also other rpm’s from `*.x86_64` type that are in dependency with the rpm from `i686` ?
2. what are the other option/s that maybe more safe to remove the rpm’s fro  `i686` type without using “*”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it will — if an `x86_64` RPM depends on an `i686` RPM, it will be removed, same as any other dependency.
2. The safest option is to leave these packages alone. However, you can instruct `yum` to remove a package as long as it doesn’t affect any `x86_64` package by running

   ```
    yum remove '*.i686' -x '*.x86_64'
   ```

   and variants thereof.

Comment: the problem is that we have many dependencies with the rpm;s i686 that actually isn't in used , so lets say that in our server we can removed all i686 rpm's but the question is how to avoid on the same time removing of x86_64 ? , if you think this is other question then I can post  another new one

Comment: Why are you focusing on i686 dependencies? If you have unused packages, you should remove them, regardless of their architecture. I don’t think it’s productive to think in terms of “removing all i686 packages”.

Comment: ok , I will think about , so about my previous note - is it possible to limit yum in order to remove only i686 rpm's? and not x86_64 , if you think this is another question , then  I will add a new post ?

Comment: ok , I see , so in that case maybe we need to perform test  that will tell if there are  Independence between rpm with i686 to x86_64  , it its true the we not removed the i686 , so my last question is - how to do this test with yum or other approach >

Comment: I mean how to verifies hat i686rpm have conflict or dependencies with x86_64 ?

Comment: I’ll ask again, why are you focusing on i686 dependencies?

Comment: because many times we failed to install rpm;s of x86_64 , because dependencies with i686  or Protected multilib versions, and after deeply verification we found that all rpm that are from i686 type are no needed !!  , so the right thing is to remove them , 1 because of dependence with x86_64  2. because all i686 are not needed on our servers !

Comment: OK, that would have been a good start to the question ;-). If all your i686 packages are truly unused, then point 1 in your question is moot, isn’t it? Or are you asking how to replace i686 packages which are installed as x86_64 dependencies with their x86_64 equivalent?

Comment: I don’t want to replace the i686 packages with X86 , because rpms from X86 are already installed  , what I am want to do , is to add a test , that will check if removal of i686 rpm is with dependence with X86 , if there are dependence then we get alert for example , "you can’t remove the i686 because of dependence with X86 " , if not then we get the message - "you can safety removed the rpm from i686 "

Comment: thank you so much about the solution - yum remove '*.i686' -x '*.x86_64' , so I guess that "-x" flag is like exclude the remval of X86? am I right ??

Comment: Pretty much; the `-x` flag causes matching packages to be ignored, so this command says “remove all i686 packages, ignoring x86_64 packages”, which means that the latter can’t be removed (and cause an error).