# yum + how to identify dependencies between rpm from i686 to X86

Tags: bash, rhel, yum, rpm, x86

The approach to remove all rpm type of i686 and exclude the removal of `X86_64` is like the following

```
yum remove '*.i686' -x '*.x86_64'
```

**what we want to do instead it like the following**

verify no dependencies between removal of rpm `i686` to `X86_64`

1. in case there are dependencies , then cli will print “don’t remove the `i686` rpm’s”
2. in case no dependencies between removal of `i686` rpm to `X86_65` , then cli will print “ you can safety to remove the rpm – `i686`” and then we can run the command - `yum remove '*.i686' -y`

so any suggestion how to check by yum or else , dependencies between `i686` rpm to `X86_64`?
and if no dependence then we can safety remove the i686 rpm's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's zero dependency between `i686` and `x86_64` packages in Fedora and RHEL/CentOS - can't say the same about all other Linux distros.

You can safely delete all `i686` packages - `x86_64` packages won't be affected.

Here on Fedora 32:

```bsh
# dnf remove --assumeno --setopt=clean_requirements_on_remove=0 \
    $(rpm -qa | grep i686) | grep x86_64 | wc -l
Operation aborted.
0
# rpm -qa | grep i686 | wc -l 
163
```

In case you're running CentOS you may replace `dnf` with `yum`.

Comment: according to @Stephen Kitt dependencies could be between i686 to X86 , see the post - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606393/yum-what-is-the-safety-approach-to-remove-all-rpms-from-i686-type-from-rhel-7

Comment: not clearly how the syntax - " yum  remove --assumeno --setopt=clean_requirements_on_remove=0 $(rpm -qa | grep i686) | grep x86_64 | wc -l"  identify if dependencies are between i686 to X86 yes or not

Comment: can we just perform that -  [[ ` rpm -qa | grep i686 | grep x86_64 | wc -l ` -ne 0 ]] && echo dont remove i686 rpm                            ( in order to identity if we can remove the i686 rpm or not ?

Comment: @Artem here’s one counter-example in Fedora 32: `wine`...

Comment: @StephenKitt They are possible, you're right but the command above should work beautifully.

Comment: @Artem your command is fine, but your first two paragraphs are incorrect.

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep i686 | grep x86_64` will return nothing.

Comment: what you think about my answer?

Answer (score -2):

other interesting approach is

```
yum --assumeno --disablerepo='*'  remove *i686 | grep  x86_64 | wc -l
```

this will capture the number of rpm of x86_64 rpm's that in dependencies with rpm of i686

or

```
yum --assumeno --disablerepo='*'  remove *i686 | grep -iq x86_64
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
echo "rpm of x86_64 rpm's are in dependencies with rpm of i686"
fi
```

Comment: I really not understand why I get -1 for my excellent answer - why?